# aws s3.copyObject return params with destination path

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy

I am using AWS' `s3.copyObject` for moving a file from source to destination. How can I get the entire path of new destination. Is there any callback params of `s3.copyObject` which gives this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such callbacks available. You need to find the path as follows

```
var s3DestinationPath = 'https://s3-'+region+'.amazonaws.com/'+bucket+ '/' + DestinationFolder + '/' + fileName ;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the copy command, you give it the bucket and key (name). You should use that, not the response object